# What is orthographic focal length?

Tags: 3d-view

Blender's viewport supports both perspective and orthographic viewing modes.

Under Sidebar(N-panel)->View there is an option called `focal length`. When in perspective mode this `focal length` is the same as the focal length option of cameras in perspective mode.
However when I switch to orthographic mode this option still stays the same, while cameras switch their `focal length` option to the `orthographic scale` option.

The orthographic scale option is pretty self explainatory in cameras but what does the `focal length` option in the orthographic mode of the viewport camera mean?

I noticed that Blender's viewport does a pretty good job at keeping object's sizes consistent while switching between perspctive and orthographic. Does Blender somehow convert the viewport `focal length` option in the background to a fitting `orthographic scale`? And if so what is the mathematical relationship?

Comment: Interesting. A focal length for an orthographic camera doesn't make much sense. I assume the same thing as you, when you tweak the viewport focal length while in orthographic, it changes the underlying orthographic scale to stay consistent with what it would look like in perspective mode. I'd like to see the maths and logic behind it though. I wonder if it wouldn't make more sense to do the same thing as with the camera objects, show the setting that makes sense and hide the other one depending on camera type

Comment: To match, you need another variable, which is depth.  I would expect this to be set from camera orbit point, and quick experiment suggests that's true.  Internally, Blender is probably using FoV as an angle rather than focal length; conversion from focal length (and sensor size, which is probably set from zoom) to FoV is dealt with elsewhere, incl. on this site.  Solving for the current bounds of the view then becomes solving for the length of one side of a right triangle with 1 known side (depth) and 3 known angles (right angle at depth plane, half of FoV at view, third takes us to 180.)

Comment: @Nathan `"Blender is probably using FoV as an angle rather than focal length; conversion from focal length (and sensor size, which is probably set from zoom)"` I know for a fact that neither zooming nor dollying changes the sensor size or focal length. In fact dollying and zooming in Blender is the same, kind of... Because of the very poor documentation and general misconceptions on viewport navigation I decided to ask the devs directly in https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-navigation/24448 Do you maybe have answers on some of my questions asked there?

Comment: You're right, it's not sensor size, unless you've adopted a camera view, in which case it is camera sensor size times a constant determined by zoom.  Without a camera view, it is probably a constant, but I don't know an experiment to determine exactly which constant that is.

Comment: I'll add that to the questions.